# Python zip with multiple arrays

Tags: python

I want to create a pandas DataFrame with a array of columns, but instead of

```
data = list(zip(column1, column2, column3))
```

I want to use something like this

```
columns = [column1, column2, column3]
data = list(zip(columns))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Unpack the list with: `data = list(zip(*columns))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use * operator in python.

```
data = list(zip(*columns))
```